# How can I add a spring security JSESSIONID with SockJS and STOMP when doing a cross-domain request?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, spring-security, stomp, sockjs

I am having the following problem. I will describe 3 use cases - two which work and the other one which doesn't.

I have an AngularJS client using SockJS with STOMP. In the backend I have a Spring application. Client is in domain domainA.com, backend is in domainB.com.

```
var socket = new SockJS(("http://domainB.com/myApp/messages"));
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {
    ...
}
```

In the backend there are Cors filters and the Cross-origin calls are possible. All works fine.

**Use Case 1.** Client domainA, Server domainB

My application is unsecured on the backend side. I subscribe like below:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/listen', function(message) {
    showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
});
```

All works fine.

**Use Case 2.** Client domainB, Server domainB

My application is secured on the backend side with Spring security. Authentication is done through a form - username and password. Nothing uncommon.

In this case the client is **on domainB.com**, same as the backend. All works fine, the difference is that I use a different subscription method:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/listen', function(message) {
    showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
});
```

in order to benefit from getting the principal from the security session. All works well. No issues.

The JSESSIONID cookie is added to the connection request in **new SockJS(("http://domainB.com/myApp/messages"));**.

**Use Case 3.** Client domainA, Server domainB

The application is secured the same as in UC2. However, the client is now on a different domain.

The JSESSIONID is **NOT** added to the connection request. The connection to websocket in Spring is unauthenticated and redirected back to login page. This repeats and makes it impossible to connect.

Why is the **JSESSIONID cookie not populated** with the websocket requests in this case?

Cheers
Adam

Answer (score 1):

As part of SockJS protocol, a http `GET` is sent to websocket server for negotiating the supported protocols. It's done using `XmlHttpRequest` which won't add any cookies stored for a different domain than its own domain the web application and scripts are served due to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) implemented in every modern web browser.

You should resort to a way of [circumventing the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the answers you are looking for here : http://spring.io/blog/2014/09/16/preview-spring-security-websocket-support-sessions

the trick to implement a HandshakeInterceptor